# What's the difference between "generated by the collection of sets $\mathscr{B}$" and "with basis $\mathscr{B}$ in topology?

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading Munkres 2nd ed. and I'm a bit confused by the language. When you consider a topology $\mathscr{T}$, are the following statements equivalent?

The topology $\mathscr{T}$ is generated by the collection of sets $\mathscr{B}$

The topology $\mathscr{T}$ has as its basis the collection of sets $\mathscr{B}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that $\mathscr B$ is a basis is a stronger claim than saying that it generates the topology.

When you say that $\mathscr B$ is a *basis* for the topology, you're claiming that every open set is a *union* of sets from $\mathscr B$.

When you say that $\mathscr B$ *generates* the topology, you may need to take *intersections* too in order to produce all open sets. (And, as an extreme case, $\bigcup\mathscr B$ may not be the entire space, but the entire space is still open, as it is required to).